# Do the names/keys of documents and fields in Cloud Firestore affect my quota?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

In the [pricing overview for Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#pricing_overview), it says (my bold highlight):

> ### Pricing overview
>
> When you use Cloud Firestore, you are charged for the following:
>
> - The number of reads, writes, and deletes that you perform.
> - The amount of storage that your database uses, **including overhead for
>     metadata and indexes**.
> - The amount of network bandwidth that you use.

Does the statement in bold mean that if I use long names/keys for fields it will affect my quota? I take it that the field names are stored for each individual document, unlike a SQL-database where column names would only be stored once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. Field names are stored inline with the data and count towards storage size. We give full details in our [Storage Size Calculations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size) of the documentation.

Storage Size Calculations

Contents
String size
Document name size
Field size
Document size
Index entry size
What's next
This page describes the storage size of documents, document names, fields, and index entries in Cloud Firestore.

> You can learn about the costs of this storage at Cloud Firestore
> Pricing. String size
>
> String sizes are calculated as the number of UTF-8 encoded bytes + 1.
>
> The following are stored as strings:
>
> - Document names
> - Collection IDs
> - Namespace names (the default namespace
>   has size 0)
> - Field names
> - String field values
>
> For example:
>
> - The ID of the Task collection uses 4 bytes + 1 byte, for a total of 5
>   bytes.
> - The name of the description field uses 11 bytes + 1 byte, for a
>   total of 12 bytes.
> - The name of the my_namespace namespace uses 13
>   bytes + 1 byte, for a total of 14 bytes.

Comment: Field names are stored once for each collection, or for EACH document. For example: If I have 20Million users, containing a `users_full_address` field. If I rename the field to just `add`, am I saving 15 bytes or 15*20Million bytes (about 300 MBs)?